# Neural Networks: Why can't I go deeper?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using this model to get depth maps from images:

```
def get_model(learning_rate=0.001, channels=2):
    h = 128  # height of the image
    w = 128  # width of the image
    c = channels  # no of channels

    encoding_size = 512

    # encoder
    image = Input(shape=(c, h, w))
    conv_1_1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(image)
    conv_1_2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_1_1)
    pool_1_2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv_1_2)

    conv_2_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_1_2)
    conv_2_2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_2_1)
    pool_2_2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv_2_2)

    conv_3_1 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_2_2)
    conv_3_2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_3_1)
    # pool_3_2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv_3_2)

    # conv_4_1 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_3_2)
    # conv_4_2 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_4_1)
    # pool_4_3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv_4_2)

    # conv_5_1 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_4_3)
    # conv_5_2 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_5_1)
    flat_5_2 = Flatten()(conv_3_2)
    encoding = Dense(encoding_size, activation='tanh')(flat_5_2)

    # decoder
    reshaped_6_1 = Reshape((8, 8, 8))(encoding)
    conv_6_1 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(reshaped_6_1)
    conv_6_2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_6_1)
    upsample_6_2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv_6_2)

    conv_7_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(upsample_6_2)
    conv_7_2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_7_1)
    upsample_7_2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv_7_2)

    conv_8_1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(upsample_7_2)
    conv_8_2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_8_1)
    upsample_8_2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv_8_2)

    conv_9_1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(upsample_8_2)
    conv_9_2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_9_1)
    upsample_9_2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv_9_2)

    conv_10_1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(upsample_9_2)
    conv_10_2 = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_10_1)
    output = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation=relu_normalized, padding='same')(conv_10_2)

    model = Model(inputs=image, outputs=output)
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate))
    return model
```

- Input: 2x128x128 (two bw images) - Squished to [0,1] (preprocessing normalization)
- Output: 1x128x128 (depth map) - Squished to [0,1] by relu-normalized

NOTE: relu_normalized is just relu followed by squishing values to 0-1 so as to have a proper image. Sigmoid doesn't seem to fit this criteria.

When I add any more layers, the loss becomes a constant and backprop is not happening properly because both the output and gradients are becoming zero (and hence changing the learning rate didn't change anything in the network)

So if I want to go deeper to generalize more, by uncommenting the lines (and of course connecting `conv_5_2` to `flat_5_2`), **what is it that I am missing?**

My thoughts:

- Using Sigmoid would lead to vanishing gradient problem, but I am using relu's, would that problem still exist?
- Changing anything in the network, like encoding size, even changing to activations to `elu` or `selu` doesn't show any progress.

**Why are my outputs getting closer to zero when I try to add even one more conv layer followed by max_pooling?**

---

UPDATE:

Here's relu_normalized,

```
def relu_normalized(x):
    epsilon = 1e-6
    relu_x = relu(x)
    relu_scaled_x = relu_x / (K.max(relu_x) + epsilon)
    return relu_scaled_x
```

and later after getting the output which has range [0,1], we simple do output_image = 255 * output and we can save this as b/w image now.

Comment: The deeper your model is, the more the gradient is vanishing. Its just because the gradients are multiplied. Relu does not solve this problem for every architecure, it is just better then other activation functions. Are you sure you need a deeper architecure? HAve you tried to change your tanh from the encoding to something else?

Comment: So how do people actually get around this vanishing gradient problem? Is there anything I can do here if I want to go deeper? Anything at all?

Comment: I trained it with 5 images and output for more than 1000 epochs just to see if the network has the ability to generalize those 5 outputs (to begin with). But the results were not satisfactory with the layers commented. So I concluded that I would need more generalizing power to make the network perform better. Also, I would need layer groups 4 and 5 in order to introduce skip connections concatenating inputs from layers before max_pooling, so as to improve upsampling layer output, and once again all these to increase the generalizing capability of the network.

Comment: I don´t think you can make any conclusions with a data set, consisting of 5 images. With 5 images, it will just learn some garbage and this could be the reason for your vanishing gradients.

Comment: I do have a huge dataset to train it with, but before that, i thought it would be sane to use just 5 images to train and see (using model.predict()) how well the network is able to fit (or overfit or underfit) just those 5. This way we can be sure that our loss function is right and the architecture is capable for well those 5, we can then think about making it fit 1000, making it more capable, while restricting it from overfitting.

Comment: Please include the code for relu_normalized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want go deeper you have to **add some batch normalization layer** (in Keras https://keras.io/layers/normalization/#batchnormalization) in this case.
From Ian Goodfellow's book, on the batch normalization chapter:

> Very deep models involve the composition of several functions or layers. The
>   gradient tells how to update each parameter, under the assumption that the other
>   layers do not change. In practice, we update all of the layers simultaneously.
>   When we make the update, unexpected results can happen because many functions
>   composed together are changed simultaneously, using updates that were computed
>   under the assumption that the other functions remain constant

Also, **`tanh` is easily saturated** so use only if you need it :)

Comment: Saturation should not be a problem if using "binary_crossentropy" or "categorical_crossentropy". Now, "relu" and similars always bring me trouble, from frozen loss to nans.

Comment: Did you normalize the images to [0,1] (on input)? (I think you did because you are using a ReLU normalized).

Comment: Maybe it is the Upsamling because it duplicate row and columns you need a Deconvolution (if you are asking whati is it https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers), you can do it with Conv2DTranspose (https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose)

Comment: @Kubaba, yes, I normalize before feeding it to the network. I also tried skip connections from just before max-pooling and feed it to upsampling layer to improve the results, but that doesn't work as well. It seems there's something not right about the introducing layer group 4 and 5, that's exactly when outputs are always zero. I'll try with deconv, and update my question. thanks :)

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran: I'm looking the relu_normalized, I was thinking, why do you need it? If you need it for seeing the representation as a image you can normalize it only when you need it.

Comment: If the relu_normalized is giving you some trouble you can try editing the cost funcion adding a restriction on that representation. Maybe you can look at Variational autoencorers (I picked a link but I didn't (fully) read it :https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-variational-autoencoders-1bfe67eb5daf)

Comment: After a lot of tweaks and directly inspecting the weights, found that the max of outpu(`wx+b` for each layer after activation) is gradually going so high and when I went even deeper, all values were approaching infinity and batch norm held them perfectly under control. And as rightly said, using `tanh` comes with the risk of saturating the values, but with BatchNorm, the range lies within [0, 50] approx and it helps keeping it under control. Without BatchNorm, the weights were going to inf and hence at relu_normalized dividing everything with inf becomes zero...!

Comment: @Kubaba I'm removing your PS, this **is** the answer :)

Comment: Adding to @Kubaba s answer, something specific to this architecture, skip connections play a big role as well in bringing the loss down

Comment: Fantastic!:) I'm glad to been helpful

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem that might happen with "relu" when you have learning rates too big.

There is a high chance of all activations going to 0 and getting stuck there never to change anymore. (When they're at 0, their gradient is also 0).

Since I'm not an expert on adjusting the parameters in detail for using "relu", and my results with "relu" are always bad, I prefer using "sigmoid" or "tanh". (It's worth trying, although there might be some vanishing there...). I keep my images ranged from 0 to 1 and use "binary_crossentropy" as loss, which is a lot faster than "mae/mse" in this case.

Another thing that happened to me was an "apparently" frozen loss function. It happened that the value was changing so little, that the displayed decimals weren't enough to see the variation, but after a lot of epochs, it found a reasonable way to go down properly. (Probably some kind of saturation indeed, but for me it's still better than getting freezes or nans)

Answer (score -1):

You can introduce recurrent layers like LSTM which would "trap" the errors using gating, potentially improving the situation.

Comment: when downvoting, please comment why it is bad. And it would server as a good reason to the dev community, in the future, as to why something is not recommended or should not be done